# Failed validating datetime field in unit testing form

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, datetime, phpunit

I'm writing a unit test and I can't pass the validation for a datetime field. This is my entity with the field that causes problems:

```
class Page
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="NOT_EMPTY")
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
     private $date;

 }
```

And here is my unit test:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('#addNew')->form();
$date = new \DateTime();
$params = array(
    'formpage[title]' => 'Unitest sample',
    'formpage[date]'  => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
$form->setValues($params);
$client->submit($form);
```

This is the error I caught using the debugger, $form->isValid() returns false:

> ```
> Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
> This value is not valid
> Unable to reverse value for property path "date": Date parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR
> ```

Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple `'formpage[date]'  => $date` won’t do the trick?

Comment: this will do the trick, otherwise you have to DateTime::createFromFormat

Comment: I tried, still don't pass validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's failing because of the expected [format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format).

It seems you've defined your widget as a single_text but haven't specified the format (or the one you specified doesn't coincide with the one you're sending). The default format is `yyyy-MM-dd` if widget is single_text ( no H:i:s part).

Correct this and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I had a format specified "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm", I removed it and now is working fine.